# When use Zener Diode and when use Voltage Regulator IC in regulating voltage?

Tags: voltage-regulator, solar-cell, zener

This question maybe general question, but I have my own case like below.

I'm planning to make solar cell phone charger.

I found 1 solar cell with this specification as follows:

```
Brand: Staryu
Type: Polycrystalline Solar Module
Model : Staryu-10w
Rated Maximum Power : 10wp
Voltage At Maximum Power : 17.5V
Current At Maximum Power : 0.571A
Open Circuit Current : 21V
Short Circuit Voltage : 0.64A
Dimensions : 354 x 251 x 18mm
Maximum system voltage : 1000V
```

Here I summaried properties (specification) that I'm sure I know its purpose.

- Max Power: 10WP (Watt-Peak)
- Max Voltage: 17.5V
- Max Current: 0.517A

We know common properties in average phone chargers are like these:

- Power: 10W
- Voltage: 5V
- Current: 2A

Since that solar cell `voltage` and `current` is not syncroun with charger properties, so I'm applying `Power Formula` so that solar cell will syncroun with phone charger.

Because current is not able to regulate, so I will regulate the voltage one. With this basic formula, all I need to do is just `reduce voltage to 5V` so that the `current will increase to 2A` as same as phone charger with Zener or IC Voltage Regulator? (still a question).

```
P = I * V
10W = I * 5V
I = 2A
```

So especially for my case, should I use Zener Diode or Voltage Regulator IC in regulating Voltage?

What simple case that we should use zener diode or voltage regulator IC?

Note:

- Correct any statements or calculation that I made if I'm wrong.

Comment: `syncroun` is not a word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Zener diode will just convert any excess voltage directly into heat, meaning that you will get 5V at 500mA. A linear regulator will do the same. Only switching regulators are able to deliver a higher current at their output than what they consume at their input (while lowering the voltage).

This means that neither a Zener diode, nor a linear voltage regulator IC will work for your purpose. You need to build a buck converter.

In general, you only use linear regulators when you need a low power, low noise voltage rail and you don't really care about efficiency. Zeners are cheaper but even less efficient and very inaccurate.